# How to provide base64 encoded data url in meta tag

Tags: javascript, html, meta, data-uri

Consider the following HTML :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <meta id="meta" http-equiv="refresh">
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">  document.getElementById("meta").content="1;url=data:text/html;base64,PFNDUklQVD5hbGVydCgiUHduZWQiKTs8L1NDUklQVD4=";
    </script>
</html>
```

If you type the data:text/html;base64,PFNDUklQVD5hbGVydCgiUHduZWQiKTs8L1NDUklQVD4= in chrome url address bar. You will get an alert.
But it doesnt happen when you use it in the meta tag above.
It shows some error -
**Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: data:text/html;base64,PFNDUklQVD5hbGVydCgiUHduZWQiKTs8L1NDUklQVD4=**

Mainly i want to auto redirect to a different page. But using the base64 encoded url.
If i do 
The page does gets redirected to google.com after a second.
But when i change the same to content="1;data:text/html;base64,aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ=="
I get the same error - Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL
Even is you paste the string : data:text/html;base64,aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ== in browser address bar it will show you http://www.google.com

I want to do it inside the HTML using javascript or direct.
Is there any way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: "*But using the base64 encoded url*" - but why? Just use the actual url.

Comment: Apart from the problem with the "*Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL*" error, your approach is wrong. You're not redirecting to the encoded url address, you're redirecting to a plain page whose *content* is the data (which should actually be an html document, but your plain text url is still displayed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about using a redirect in javascript like explained here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp within an `onload()` function

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- ... -->
  <script>
  function myRedirectFunction() {
    // option 1 
    // window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";
    // option 2
    window.location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="myRedirectFunction()">
   <!-- ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks I think that will do rather than doing something with meta.

Comment: np, you can accept the answer to solve your problem by the way